# Jquery Replace Second and Third Word

Tags: jquery, regex

Im trying to replace the second and third word in an html element.

so far I can replace the second word using this:

```
jQuery("article#box-1 h2.join-box-head").each(function(i, v){
  newHTML = jQuery(this).html()
  .replace(/\s(.*?)\s/,'<span class="error">$1 </span>')
  jQuery(this).html(newHTML);
});
```

but im having a hard time selecting the third word too

**HTML**

```
<article id="box-1">
    <h2 class="join-box-head">JOIN WITH YOUR FAMILY</h2>
    </article>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide please your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is regex really needed?

```
jQuery("article#box-1 h2.join-box-head").each(function(i, v){
    var newHTML = jQuery(this).html().split(" ");
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        newHTML[i] = '<span class="error">' + newHTML[i] + '</span>';
    jQuery(this).html(newHTML.join(" "));
});
```

Or both in one span

```
jQuery("article#box-1 h2.join-box-head").each(function(i, v){
    var newHTML = jQuery(this).html().split(" ");
    newHTML[1] = '<span class="error">' + newHTML[1];
    newHTML[2] = newHTML[2] + '</span>';
    jQuery(this).html(newHTML.join(" "));
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to add both words into one span?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is not efficient but fast would be to call the funcion you provided twice, because when you replace the second word, the third word becomes the second word. So, call the same function twice if you do not want to make any code changes and you do not care about performance efficiency.

Comment: the problem is it nests the replacement in it